# Brain Teaser Problem ? Finding height when area is only given.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**The area of the east wall of an auditorium is 108 sq m, the area of the north wall is 135 sq m and the area of the floor is 180 sq m. Find the height of the auditorium.?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the height be $h$, and the length of the east and north sides of the floor be $x$ and $y$ respectively.

Then the area of the floor is $xy$, the area of the east wall is $hx$, and the area of the north wall is $hy$. In particular, notice that if we multiply the area of the two walls together, we get $hx \times hy = h^2 xy = h^2 \times \mbox{ area of the floor}$.

That should be enough to solve for $h$.

Comment: i don't get it. Can you solve it with the problem mentioned above.

Comment: If you multiply the areas of the east and north walls together, you get $108 \times 135$, and that's equal to $(height \times width) \times (height \times length)$, or rearranging, $height \times height \times length \times width$.

But we already know that $length \times width = 180$, so $108 \times 135 = height^2 \times 180$. So $height^2 = 108 \times 135 \div 180$, and just calculate and take the square root.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the auditorium is a $L \times H \times W$ rectangular box, you have $WH = 108$, $LH = 135$ and $LW = 180$.  Then $LWH = \sqrt{108 \times 135 \times 180}$.  Divide by $LW=180$ and you have $H$.

Comment: Is there any other method not involving finding sqrt(108×135×180).